# WSS protocol vs HTTPS protocol as an iframe embedded source in a web page

Tags: tls, web-application, html, web

until recently, I've been embedding a chatbot service from a different/external site with an iframe tag.

it's a paid service, not a free one.

today I saw that they changed a few urls, swithing from "https://" to "wss://"

I have concerns about the "wss" protocol when it comes to the security of my site visitors.

I've read about the "wss" protocol but can't conclude if it's **less secure** for my site visitors.

does it have **more** potential to hurt of my site visitors?
does it have any security dangers **that the previous ("https") one did not have**?

Comment: Are you sure that they asked you exactly this? Because this would not work in my understanding: The `src` argument for an iframe expects a document to render, i.e. it will issue a single request for the URL and get a single response back which then gets rendered in the iframe. WebSocksts (ws, wss) does not provide this kind of semantics though, i.e. there is nothing to render here.

Comment: sorry, I see now it's the same embed code, but the urls in various places was switched from "https" to "wss". (I edited the post). 
the question remains: does wss have any additional security issues compared to the https protocol? maybe because it goes both ways, from client to server as well

Answer (score 2):

WSS is just WebSockets (WS) over TLS, similar how HTTPS is just HTTP over TLS. Using WS or WSS by itself does neither introduce new risks to the client side, nor does it add additional protection.

Of course, a site is not just switching from HTTPS to WSS by simply changing the URLs in the code but it must also change the code around these URLs. New vulnerabilities might be added this way but this is not specific to the use of WSS vs. HTTPS.